# import bitcoin seed

Tags: import

Hello everyone I need to know in which wallet I can import my seed like the one in the next photo which is an example, it is not the real one, I do not remember which page years ago gave me this as a seed and I found it after believing it lost and I want to recover My funds in which wallet I can do, greetings

Answer (score 2):

First, you can edit your question instead of answering to it to add details.

Second, what you provided is not a seed as in BIP32 seed from which you get a master key and then can derive other keys from it.

This is a private key, as in the private key of a private-public key pair.

An answer to your question is the Bitcoin core implementation wallet allows you to import a single priv key with command `importprivkey`:

```
bitcoin-cli importprivkey 5JtfaH........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Electrum wallet, which is very user friendly. (Link: https://electrum.org/#download)

Once you've set up the wallet you can do **Wallet** > **Private Keys** > **Sweep** to send your coins to your new wallet, and then spend them.